# Problem with Delphi 10.3 Community PaintBox Repaint-Function

Tags: windows, delphi, pascal

I am currently making a little Program in Delphi 10.3 Community Version 26.0.34749.6593. No additional components.

Essentially I draw on TPaintBox which is fitted in a Panel. Everything works fine so far, but when the objects are repainted via "PaintBox1.Repaint" the Objects got the wrong BrushStyle (bsSolid when they should have bsClear e.g.) Of course I tried to pin it down, but I got no luck. But I found out that at the following Point something doesn't work:

```
    procedure TForm1.PaintBox1Paint(Sender: TObject);
    var
        i: Integer;
        fig : ^TFigure;
        apen: TPenStyle;
        abrush: TBrushStyle;
        color1,color2: TColor;

    begin
        aPen := PaintBox1.Canvas.Pen.Style;
        aBrush := bsStyle;
        color1 := PaintBox1.Canvas.Brush.Color;
        color2 := PaintBox1.Canvas.Pen.Color;

        for I:=0 to List.Count-1 do
        begin
          fig := List.Items[i];
          case fig.Typ of
                f_Kreis : begin
                          with Paintbox1.Canvas do
                          begin
                            pen.Style := fig.Pen;
                            Brush.Style := fig.Brush;
                            pen.Color := fig.PenColor;
                            brush.Color := fig.BrushColor;
                            Ellipse(fig.X,fig.Y,fig.X2,fig.Y2);
                          end;
                          end;
                f_Rechteck :    begin
                                  with PaintBox1.Canvas do
                                  begin
                                       Pen.Style := fig.Pen;
                                       Brush.Style := fig.Brush;
                                       Pen.Color := fig.PenColor;
                                       Brush.Color := fig.BrushColor;
                                       Rectangle(fig.X,fig.Y,fig.X2,fig.Y2);
                                  end;
                                end;
                f_Line :  begin
                            with PaintBox1.Canvas do
                            begin
                              pen.Style := fig.Pen;
                              brush.Style := fig.Brush;
                              pen.Color := fig.PenColor;
                              brush.Color := fig.BrushColor;
                              MoveTo(fig.X,Fig.Y);
                              LineTo(fig.X2,fig.Y2);
                            end;
                          end;
          end;
        end;



        PaintBox1.Canvas.Pen.Style := aPen;
        bsStyle := aBrush;
        PaintBox1.Canvas.Brush.Color := color1;
        PaintBox1.Canvas.Pen.Color := color2;
     end;
```

So when the "Brush.Style := fig.Brush;"-Line is called, nothing happens. I went step by step and after these Line "Brush.Style" is still "bsSolid" even when "fig.Brush" is "bsClear"

For explanation: TFigure is my own class. It houses information about a drawing, such as a rectangle. It is the parent class.

Do I miss something. I really am out of Ideas. Can anyone tell me, why nothing happens?

Edit:

For testing I added the lines:

```
if Brush.Style <> fig.Brush then
   ShowMessage('Warnung!');
```

under

```
Brush.Style := fig.Brush;
```

and it actually wont set it on false, though Brush.Style is bsSolid and fig.Brush is bsClear.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: The definition for `TFigure` and the init of the `List.Items` is missing from the pasted code. Maybe that's where the problem is?

Comment: You will likely have to enable Debug DCUs and step into the VCL source code to find out why the `Brush.Style` property setter is not taking your values. Not sure if you can do that with the Community Edition, though.

Comment: @nolaspeaker TFigure is defined in another Unit, which is included in the uses-clause. I controlled it after your post. ;) and the List (Which is a TList) is initiated in the Form-Create-Method. And so far TFigure and the List work. Inside the List the correct BrushStyle is stated.

Comment: @ and that was 07:00 pm here in Germany. Sorry, but I also have family duties. And have to wake up at 04:30 am.

Comment: SO users are in many different time-zones all over the world. You don't have to explain. We are patient.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be nice to look at *the full source code* to help you. How do you fill `TFigure` instances with data? For example, I can't get what this line means: *bsStyle := aBrush;*. Also you could reduce the size of your code, merged repeated instructions in one block.

Answer (score 2):

You have declared `fig : ^TFigure;`, but class instances are already references (pointers). Thus you are creating a pointer to reference, and using that pointer as if it were the reference.

Remove the pointer operator and declare

```
fig: TFigure;
```

I can't verify whether there are other errors in your code